# Can we use .lib file using GCC compiler

Tags: gcc, linker, lib

I have a library file with .lib extension. I want to use this file in my project which uses GCC compiler to build.

Is it possible to use the .lib file?? I tried but I got this error:

```
"File Format not recognized."
```

Comment: In which condition did you get this error?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11793370/1212012) could interess you.